# Admob + Phonegap Doesn't work on Android 2.1

Tags: android, cordova, admob

I have successfully got Admob to show in my 4.0.4 emulator and also on my 4.0.4 phone but when I run the 2.1 emulator and try it on my 2.1 phone I get a 'no network' 
error and nothing shows up.

```
04-10 10:33:38.683: I/Ads(256): Network is unavailable.  Aborting ad request.
04-10 10:33:38.693: D/webviewglue(256): nativeDestroy view: 0x73eac0
04-10 10:33:38.693: I/Ads(256): onFailedToReceiveAd(A network error occurred.)
04-10 10:33:38.693: W/webcore(256): Can't get the viewWidth after the first layout
```

This is the code i'm using:

```
public class MyPhoneGapActivity extends DroidGap {

private Handler mHandler = new Handler();
private AdView adView;
/** Called when the activity is first created. */

public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    super.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/www/index.html");

    mHandler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            doStuff();
        }
    }, 5000); 
}
private void doStuff() {
    final String MY_AD_UNIT_ID = "MY_ID";
    AdView adView; 
    // Create the adView 
    adView = new AdView(this, AdSize.BANNER, MY_AD_UNIT_ID); 
    LinearLayout layout = super.root; // this is the only change from the sample 
    // Add the adView to it 
    layout.addView(adView); 
    // Initiate a generic request to load it with an ad 
    adView.loadAd(new AdRequest());
}
```

Manifest:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7" 
android:targetSdkVersion="13"/>

  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

  <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize" />
```

Project.properties

```
target=android-13
```

It seems that if I change the android:configChanges to the below, the ads banner shows but contains an message saying 'You must have an adActivity declared in the android manifest.xml with config changes.

```
 <activity android:name="com.google.ads.AdActivity" android:configChanges="keyboard|keyboardHidden|orientation|" />
```

Thanks

Comment: Why are you targeting 2.1?

Comment: Just so the most amount of people can use the app.

Comment: Does your emulator or device have an internet connection? Can you hit web pages on it?

Comment: I've seen 8 devices running 2.1 over the last 3 months. 40,000+ installs across 9 apps. It's infinitesimal. I even dropped 2.2 so I could use some gingerbread features, as there was less than 1% of devices running 2.2. Most are 4.0+

Comment: 1 more thing, phonegap runs like mud on <4.0. I'd target 4+ with hardware accelleration if you insist on using PhoneGap (don't - rather go native, it's quicker to dev and debug)

Comment: Yes I have an Internet connection, I even added the Phonegap online event to check. Darryn - thanks for the reply, my phonegap app runs fine on 2.1 and above so i thought that I may as well let people download it. I think i'll just leave the admob code in, if it works then fine, if not then i'm not losing anything. thanks again.

Comment: try to re-implement admob into your application, check this link it looks nice to start with snapshots http://pushnotification.blogspot.com/2013/05/integrating-admobs-native-android-sdk.html